# Finding and displaying duplicate values using WHERE IN to compare two values

Tags: mysql, count, duplicates, having, where-in

I have a `MYSQL` database where I would like to compare duplicated values based on two values in a column. For Example

**Database**

```
field_one | field_two | field_three 
------------------------------------
aaa       | 123       | no1
bbb       | 456       | no1
aaa       | 123       | no2
ccc       | 456       | no3 
aaa       | 123       | no3
```

I would like to return these results

```
field_one | field_two | field_three 
------------------------------------
aaa       | 123       | no1
aaa       | 123       | no2
```

Here is the `query` I've been using but I'm not sure how to get my desired result. When I run the `query` in `phpMyAdmin` my browser just gets stuck. My database is also large too.

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE field_three IN (SELECT field_one, field_two FROM table_name WHERE field_three IN ('no1', 'no2') HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)`

Thanks

---

**SOLVED**

I just changed `WHERE` @Gordon Linoff 's from `query`.

```
select t.*
from table_name t join
     (select field_one, field_two
      from table_name t
      group by field_one, field_two
      having count(*) = 2   -- or do you mean >= 2?
     ) tsum
     on t.field_one = tsum.field_one and t.field_two = tsum.field_two WHERE field3 IN ('no1', 'no2')
```

Comment: your outer select doesn't make sense. Phrase your question not in sql perhaps?

Also I guess 'product' is field_three and you forgot to abstract it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select field_one, field_two
      from t
      group by field_one, field_two
      having count(*) = 2   -- or do you mean >= 2?
     ) tsum
     on t.field_one = tsum.field_one and t.field_two = tsum.field_two
```

The subquery finds the duplicates based on the first two columns.  The outer query returns the original rows.

If you want duplicates relative to another value, then add that condition to the subquery:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select field_one, field_two
      from t
      where field3 = 'no1' -- or whatever you want to set it to
      group by field_one, field_two
      having count(*) = 2   -- or do you mean >= 2?
     ) tsum
     on t.field_one = tsum.field_one and t.field_two = tsum.field_two
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. This returns all of the duplicates from the whole database. I would like to only return duplicate values based on another field's value. Let's say i want to see where `field_three` values `no1` and `no2` are duplicate.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I tried the second code but I am getting an error `#1604` near `'tsum on t.field_one = tsum.field_one and t.field_two = tsum.field_two`.

Comment: Nevermind I added the table name infront of `tsum`, however, the query is not returning anything at all. I will keep at it, Thank you again.